# Meteor.js and Custom OpenId Connect server

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

How to do authentication via custom token server in Meteor.js?

Is there any package like accounts-google for custom token server which handles authentication by just taking token endpoints, client id, secrete, and scope as configuration parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of a generic oauth package. But it shouldn't be too difficult to write a package for your particular server, as there are a number of examples to look at.

Using accounts-github as an example, here's the [code](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/release/METEOR%401.0.3.2/packages/github/github_client.js) for making the connection on the client. Note the endpoint URL, client id, scope, etc. This will handle the popup for you, but you'll probably want to include custom CSS:

```
var loginUrl =
  'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize' +
  '?client_id=' + config.clientId +
  '&scope=' + flatScope +
  '&redirect_uri=' + OAuth._redirectUri('github', config) +
  '&state=' + OAuth._stateParam(loginStyle, credentialToken);

OAuth.launchLogin({
  loginService: "github",
  loginStyle: loginStyle,
  loginUrl: loginUrl,
  credentialRequestCompleteCallback: credentialRequestCompleteCallback,
  credentialToken: credentialToken,
  popupOptions: {width: 900, height: 450}
});
```

And here's a snippet from the [server](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/release/METEOR%401.0.3.2/packages/github/github_server.js) side, completing the process to get an access token:

```
var getAccessToken = function (query) {
  var config = ServiceConfiguration.configurations.findOne({service: 'github'});
  if (!config)
    throw new ServiceConfiguration.ConfigError();

  var response;
  try {
    response = HTTP.post(
      "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token", {
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          "User-Agent": userAgent
        },
        params: {
          code: query.code,
          client_id: config.clientId,
          client_secret: OAuth.openSecret(config.secret),
          redirect_uri: OAuth._redirectUri('github', config),
          state: query.state
        }
      });
  } catch (err) {
    throw _.extend(new Error("Failed to complete OAuth handshake with Github. " + err.message),
                   {response: err.response});
  }
  if (response.data.error) { // if the http response was a json object with an error attribute
    throw new Error("Failed to complete OAuth handshake with GitHub. " + response.data.error);
  } else {
    return response.data.access_token;
  }
};
```

And utilizing the token to get the user identity:

```
var getIdentity = function (accessToken) {
  try {
    return HTTP.get(
      "https://api.github.com/user", {
        headers: {"User-Agent": userAgent}, // http://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required
        params: {access_token: accessToken}
      }).data;
  } catch (err) {
    throw _.extend(new Error("Failed to fetch identity from Github. " + err.message),
                   {response: err.response});
  }
};
```

The [github](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/release/METEOR%401.0.3.2/packages/github) and the [accounts-github](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/release/METEOR%401.0.3.2/packages/accounts-github) packages should be very helpful as references.